# Web based image uploader and editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image

Can anyone please recommend an image uploader and image editor that I can include in my web based application.

I need to be able to upload images to the site

Allow the users to edit/crop/adjust the image and then save the image to the site

I've had a look around Google and come up only with Telerik which is way too expensive for this project.

The site is ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy to find Javascript-based plugins to crop and adjust images (example: http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php)

The edition part... I've never try this, but there is a library (Javascript too) that it supposed to do that: http://www.pixastic.com/lib/

Good luck!